# How to split a string to only get characters/words

Tags: java, string

I have an arbitrary string that will always contain at least one English word followed by a series of numbers: `"Hello World 1234"` how do I extract only `"Hello World"` from the string?

Comment: I've tried str.split("[a-zA-Z]") and it does not return `"Hello World"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems to me like you need to opposite regex:

```
String[] words = "Hello World 1234".split("[0-9]");
System.out.println(words[0].trim());
```

output:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of all non-alphabetical characters in the entire string, use this.

`String test = "Hello World 1234";`

`String onlyWords = test.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\ ]+", "");`

Breakdown:

`[a-zA-Z]` - a through z or A through Z, inclusive (range)

`^` - negation

`\` - literal space character (to maintain spaces between words)